# Fibre restriction and Leray–Hirsch

Tags: cohomology, fibre-bundles

Let $\mathbb{C}P^h\to E\to B$ be a bundle which is cohomologically trivial via Leray–Hirsch, i.e. if we denote $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^h)\cong \mathbb{Z}[\mu]/\mu^{h+1}$, we have a class $\chi\in H^2(E)$ and an isomorphism
$$H^*(B)\otimes H^*(\mathbb{C}P^h)\to H^*(E), \alpha\otimes\mu^s\mapsto \pi^*\alpha\smile \chi^s$$
Now consider a class $\vartheta\in H^{2s}(E)$ with the property

> For each $x\in B$ and each fibre inclusion $\imath_x:\mathbb{C}P^h\to E$, we have $\imath_x^*\vartheta=\mu^s$.

Can we conclude $\vartheta=\chi^s$?

Comment: No, because $\theta$ plus any class pulled back from $B$ has the same property.

Comment: Okay … am I correct that the kernel of each $\imath_x^*$ is given by all elements of the form $\sum_{k\le s-1}\chi^k\smile\pi^*\alpha_k$ where $\alpha_k\in H^{2s-2k}(B)$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.